# "error: cvc-elt.1: Invalid type" when validating xml in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm having trouble validating an XML file in Java, I keep getting the "Invalid type" error. I've been Googling and found some SO threads, which told me to add the namespace in the XML and add "ns:" everywhere, but to no avail.

The XML:

```
<ns:Content xmlns:ns="http://namespace">
  <ns:Request>
    <ns:FromDateTime>20130726161606</ns:FromDateTime>
    <ns:RemainderOffset/>
    <ns:MaxResults>100</ns:MaxResults>
  </ns:Request>
  <ns:Response>
    <ns:Status>
      <ns:Code>200</ns:Code>
    </ns:Status>
    <ns:Remainder>
      <ns:Count>2828</ns:Count>
      <ns:Offset>126690959</ns:Offset>
    </ns:Remainder>
    <ns:Items>
      <ns:Item id="126752560" itemHash="-1686318559">
        <ns:Title>[…]</ns:Title>
        <ns:Description>[…]</ns:Description>
        <ns:PubDate>Thu, 05 Sep 2013 06:00:27 GMT</ns:PubDate>
        <ns:Uri>[…]</ns:Uri>
        <ns:Resource>[…]</ns:Resource>
        <ns:Keywords>
          <ns:Keyword>[…]</ns:Keyword>
        </ns:Keywords>
      </ns:Item>
    </ns:Items>
  </ns:Response>
</ns:Content>
```

The schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://namespace"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://namespace"
       elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="Content">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Request">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:long" name="FromDateTime"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="RemainderOffset"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="MaxResults"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Response">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Status">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="Code"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Remainder">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Count"/>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Offset"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Items">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Title"/>
                                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Description"/>
                                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="PubDate"/>
                                                <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="Uri"/>
                                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Resource"/>
                                                <xs:element name="Keywords">
                                                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Keyword" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"  use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="itemHash" use="required"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And of course the code I use to read the file. It's a file I download first and it enters the method as `Object o`. I think the error is in here somewhere since the XML validates for this schema using online tools... I removed the try-catch blocks for readability.

```
main method {
    File file = (File) o;
    DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = b.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


    // Add the correct namespace to the xml so there won't be any false positive errors
    // Got this part from SO
    Element originalDocumentElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
    Element newDocumentElement = doc.createElementNS(NAMESPACE, originalDocumentElement.getNodeName());
    newDocumentElement.setPrefix("ns");
    NodeList list = originalDocumentElement.getChildNodes();
    while(list.getLength()!=0) {
        newDocumentElement.appendChild(list.item(0));
    }
    // Replace the original element
    doc.replaceChild(newDocumentElement, originalDocumentElement);

    xmlOptions = createXmlOptions();
    xmlDoc = XmlObject.Factory.parse(doc, xmlOptions);
    validate();
}
public XmlOptions createXmlOptions()
{
    Map<String, String> substituteNamespaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
    substituteNamespaces.put("", "http://namespace");
    XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();
    xmlOptions.setLoadSubstituteNamespaces(substituteNamespaces);
    xmlOptions.setCharacterEncoding(FILE_ENCODING);
    xmlOptions.setErrorListener(errors);
    xmlOptions.setValidateTreatLaxAsSkip();
    return xmlOptions;
}

public boolean validate() throws ParserException {

    return xmlDoc.validate(xmlOptions);
}
```

Error message: error: cvc-elt.1: Invalid type

Printing `error.getCursorLocation().xmlText()` returns the entire XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why I got this error, but to anyone facing the same problem: use [XML Beans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). Very easy to set up and even easier to use. I was able to reuse a lot of my code and it worked instantly.

Answer (score 2):

The schema is for namespace

```
targetNamespace="http://red.persgroep.be/technology/1.0"
```

It has nothing to say about documents in namespace

```
xmlns:ns="http://namespace"
```

You can only validate elements against a schema that is applicable to the element's namespace.

Comment: That was an edit error, sorry. It's for my work so I edited the name so it wouldn't come up on Google on unrelated searches. Could you edit/remove it please? I changed it in my question.

Comment: It's a good idea to get your questions right first time. There's nothing more infuriating than finding a bug in the posted code, only to be told it was a cut and paste error, and the code we were supposed to be debugging wasn't what you showed us.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ns:EndDateTime/>
```

is an `EndDateTime` element whose value is the empty string, and I don't think this is valid for an element whose type is `xs:long`.  You have declared the element both as `minOccurs="0"` and `nillable="true"`, so you have two choices of ways to represent the absence of an `EndDateTime` value - you can either leave the element out altogether or you can mark it as nil using

```
<ns:EndDateTime xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Comment: I forgot to say this in the question. When I tested the schema online, I got an error for this too so I removed it from both the xml and the xsd and still got the error. What is the best to use if EndDateTime can be filled in or not? I'll remove those lines from the question since this will probably give an error too, but it's not this one, unfortunately.

Comment: @IvoVdv you would generally declare something as _either_ optional _or_ nillable but not both, which you use is up to you, as both have the same sort of effect (e.g. in Java JAXB both `xsi:nil` and omitted would map to a property value of Java `null`).  There are some cases where it's useful to allow both optional and nillable, for example if you're using XML to define configuration files where values in one file can override values in another - an omitted element might mean "inherit the previous value", a `nil` might mean "override with null".

Comment: Thank you, changed it to minOccurs="0", now the complete xml validates if I use an online tool. The initial error still remains though.